# How to print the array value in cells lable?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am developing a application in that I want to print the array value in the cell contain label place. I got the vlaues for array like `names=[results valueForKey:@"name"].`

I write the code for print that value in a lable in cellForRowAtIndexPath like

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    { 

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    NSInteger row=indexPath.row;

    cell = [self getCellContentView:CellIdentifier];
    UILabel *lblTemp1 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        lblTemp1.text = [names objectAtIndex:row];
    //lblTemp2.text = [names objectAtIndex:row];
    return cell;
}
```

but ,when the application got the error at `lblTemp1.text = [names objectAtIndex:row]` like Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.So please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: does the array contains objects? debug that

Comment: Check whether the values in the arrays are present by using NSLog before adding it to the Label

Comment: Paste all the output of the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you've missed to *retain* the array *names*. Try,

```
names = [[results valueForKey:@"name"] retain];
```

You could consider using *declared properties* to overcome the overhead of retaining and releasing the objects.

Answer (score 0):

seems to be new bee. please check out for step by step tutorial

http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-part-1-uitableview-using-nsarray/